# Customer has corp. Facebook acc't I want to login for plugin code, can I have my own login?

Tags: facebook, user-accounts

What's the rule of thumb for web-masters helping their clients when it comes to getting Facebook code pertinent to the clients account?

E.g. I want to get the code for social plugins for my clients Facebook account so I can put them on their website, which of these sounds right:

1. do I need to login to their FB account/page with their login
2. am I able to get a FB login for their account
3. am I able to get the generic code from my own FB account and use an ID (etc) of my clients to make the coe work for their account?

Thanks in advance for any help. Cheers, -Alan

Comment: So, basically, should you ask for your client's account details when installing social plugins?

Comment: Your question isn't clear here - what are you trying to do here that can't be done via the regular app management interface? Why would you need access to the client's Facebook account or vice-versa?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Number 3 is right.**

What you will really need is just their Facebook ID
(which you can find out for example here by just pasting their profile url http://findmyfacebookid.com/)

for example when setting up their "like button" you can put their ID as admin (it will take effect only after they will press the like button so nobody will become admin without consent)

of course it would be easier to answer you question if you specified what do you exactly want to do.
cheers